# Folder and file are not getting created by Java code under Linux, but it works for Windows

Tags: java, linux, file

I have a few questions about Java's io.file class

1. Linux: does the file seperator operator  '//' work or do we need to use '\'?
2. In red hat there is no drive partion name so how to give the Linux equivalent of the Windows path 'c://TempFolder//Images//'?

Comment: Linux file system has a single root - /  Even NTFS volumes are mounted are under that root.  The file separator on Linux is '/'.  Some Java software will work with '/' on both OS systems.  However, in Windows, the proper representation is '\\'

Comment: File separator is the single forward slash /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Under Windows:**

```
File file = new File("C:\\TempFolder\\Images");
File file = new File("C:/TempFolder/Images"); // Because Windows soemtimes is nice.
```

**Under Linux:**

```
File file = new File("/TempFolder/Images");
```

The reason having two backslashes (`\\`), is that in strings a backslash must be escaped: `\t` being a tab character etcetera.

There are no drive letters in Linux, if that was your question. For temporary files you might use [File.createTemporaryFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29) or createTemporaryDirectory.

Directories on other computers may also be used without drive letters, but with UNC paths:

**Windows**:

```
\\Server\Directory\Directory
"\\\\Server\\Directory\\Directory"
```

**Linux**:

```
//Server/Directory/Directory
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the static field `File.separator` or, better, use the nio Paths class like this:

```
File f = Paths.get( "dir1", "dir2", "dir3" ).toFile();
```

To get something to refer to the absolute path, start the String arguments with a File.separator, which you might get also with nio with this method:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getSeparator%28%29